# Prevent iframe reload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on a pdf viewer page with angularjs (although the same problem would probably occur with angular or react). 
The document itself is embeded with the *pdf-box* in an iframe. The problem is that when switching from one layout type to another all the documents are getting downloaded again, causing unneccessary requests and bad UX. Using *ng-show*  instead of *ng-if* causes some documents to be downloaded multiple times.

Here a small piece of how the component is structured:

```
<div class="doc-container">

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-if="model.currentLayout.Label == '1'">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <pdf-box doc="model.slots[0].doc"></pdf-box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-if="model.currentLayout.Label == '1x2'">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <pdf-box doc="model.slots[0].doc"></pdf-box>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <pdf-box doc="model.slots[1].doc"></pdf-box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Some ideas that I have:

- Try with ng-include or $templateCache, just for the iframe internally, not sure if it would work though.
- Use pdf.js and cache the documents as base64 strings. That would prevent the additional http requests but would still cause the previously opened documents to be "restarted" to page 0, causing again a bad UX.

It seems to me that there might be a much easier solution in front of my eyes.

Is there a way to force the browser to "reuse" an existing iframe src after DOM manipulation?

Comment: Thanks Mike for the edit.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?